# VS Code Jupyter incorrect display

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, save, jupyter, display

The code inside the blocks is not displayed as it actually is. The problem occurs randomly. The only solution is to cut (ctrl + x) all the code and paste it in a new block. If I save the file and then reopen it, code is then displayed as it is shown in the Error.

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8ud7.png)
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apkDu.png)

I have the following extensions installed: Python, Python Extension Pack, Pylance, Kite AI Code Autocomplete, VS Code Jupyter Notebook Previewer, Jupyter and MagicPython.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would be the issue. But the Python and Jupyter extensions are built to work together. Do you need VS Code Jupyter Notebook Previewer in the mix? That might be not playing well with the Jupyter extension. You could try temporarily disabling that one and retrying the scenario.

Comment: @IanHuff, Thanks. I disabled all the supporting extensions, but the problem still happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the information you provided, I installed the extension you used, and the code can be executed correctly. Although I did not encounter the problem you described, you could refer to the following:

1. In VSCode, the Jupyter notebook function is provided by the [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python), please try to reinstall the Python extension and use the latest version of the Python extension.
2. I noticed in the screenshot that the Jupyter cell you created has reached 278. Please create a new Jyputer file and enter the code.
3. In order to avoid the interference between the extensions and affect the use, please try to keep the extensions "Python" and "Pylance" and disable other extensions, then reload VSCode (`F1`, `Developer: Reload Window`) or restart VSCode, and recreate the Jupyter file.